# What changes to workflow service will break existing workflow instances

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

My team is beginning to use Windows Workflow Foundation, and are early in the process. We have been trying to research what changes we make will break workflows that are currently in process.

Anyone with experience that can answer (or point me in the direction of good documentation) this would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider **all** changes to a workflow definition a breaking change that will prevent existing instances from reloading. There are a few minor exceptions but for all intents and purposes you can ignore those.

With WF4.5 we get the ability to add version information to workflow instances and create update maps to convert state from one version to another. See my blog post [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2011/10/11/what-s-new-in-windows-workflow-foundation-in-net-4-5-part-3.aspx) for some more details that where made public.

Comment: Great! I hadn't heard about WF4.5 - versioning sounds VERY helpful.

Comment: In the absence of WF4.5, what are some ways that you (or anyone else, for that matter) have handled versioning? It's unclear when we would be able to begin using 4.5...

Comment: One way that comes to mind might be to create "manual" version management (naming conventions?), preventing our UI from creating old versions, but leaving them in play so that existing instances can complete. That seems pretty ugly and to have a high potential for issues...

Comment: It really depends on the hosting scenario. In the case of WorkflowApplication you need to all the work anyway so it is easy. In the case of the WorkflowServiceHost you need to create multiple hosts and use the WCF router to send messages to the correct host.

Comment: We're using WorkflowServiceHost, so I guess we'll have to do multiple hosts. Does that mean new service references for each host? I've never used the WCF router before.

Comment: See [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/11/16/versioning-long-running-workflow-services-in-wf4-the-code.aspx) and [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/11/04/versioning-long-running-workflow-services-in-wf4.aspx) for two blog posts explaining the mechanism.

Comment: Thanks so much for the additional posts. They really help me understand what my team will need to do...